Delphi form doen't minimize as it should
I am trying to minimize Delphi fmx form with a custom button; but for some reason it doesn't minimize fully:
Before:
[]

Button code:
procedure TForm_Main.Button_MinClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WindowState := TWindowState.wsMinimized;
end;

I changed some of the form settings :
BorderStyle  : None
BorderIcon   : I deselected them all 
Transparency : True

and the rest is just some panels with buttons in them (I did custom there style - I am using Delphi 12.1)

I cannot reproduce, but I use Delphi 11, and I have no idea which style you are using. Do you see the same problem with an ordinary (and no style) unmodified form?

no but unfortunately i need to customize my style from scratch (even when i try to minimize the form with it original border buttons it do me the same problem)

I'm not sure I get it correctly, but if the problem is visible only with your style, then you must include that style file in your question. Please edit your question and include the style file.

Another possibility is, that this QA applies. In that case youre question is a duplicate.

I see this happen often with some of my apps as well. I have two FMX apps and they both do this every now and then. I don't know the cause of it though, but I've seen this in Delphi 11.3, 12.0 and 12.1

yes @TomBrunberg that is the case after  i test it(it is working perfectly) so all i have to do is to  switch the order of forms in my project thanks a lot
